# Is it possible to add MouseMotionListener to BufferedImage?

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, mousemotionevent

I am developing an application that drag and scale image in Jpanel.

The image is stored inside a JLabel.

But when i am adding the MouseMotionListener to the panel, then whole window is dragging and when i am trying to add MouseMotionListener to I can't select the sides of image to scale it.

So can i directly add MouseMotionListener to BufferedImage?

With any component I add MouseMotionListener, it don't allow me to select sides of image.
sides means all direction for to scale image.

Window :

```
        addMouseListener(handler);
        addMouseMotionListener(handler);
```

JLabel :

```
        label.addMouseListener(new MouseHandler());
        label.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseHandler());
```

Here `MouseHandler` is a class defined for various operation like `mousePressed`, `mouseDragged`, `mouseMove`, etc.

**Any idea why it is behaving like that?**

Comment: Why you don't put the MouseMotionListener at the JLabel?

Comment: @Gerret - i have added it to JLabel but it's not work because when i am trying to select any corner or direction of image it will not work because i have applied it on JLabel and Jlabel in into JPanel so where the co-ordinate of JLabel is i don't know.

Comment: What about to put the Image directly on the Panel...

Comment: And another question is actully enough place to resize the picture grapically. What about if you only use a input field? And display than the resized picture at the Label?

Comment: @Gerret - when i am trying to add Image Directly to JPanel it shows me an error. i have write code : `JPanel j; j.add(a);` here a is instance of BufferedImage. it shows error that a should be component or add method take component as an argument.

Comment: okok your right and what is with my other solution or you dont like that :)

Comment: that actually i don't understand, will you elaborate it ?

Comment: I may will help you... xD But thats a lot easyer than to make it graphically movable or dont you think so? Just use a inputbox where the user is able to put the size of the picture and than resize it and show it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35995/discussion-between-user2659972-and-gerret)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BufferedImage` is a class that supports general image manipulation. It can be used equally from interactive programs with a graphical user interface, and from non-interactive batch processing programs with no user interface. Having a mouse listener on something that is not used in a GUI does not make sense, so you can't add a `MouseMotionListener` to a `BufferedImage`.

You should add the listener to the GUI component that is showing the image instead.